# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, webpack

I followed the instructions at [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/) thinking that everything would just work. It isn't so far :\

Everything seems to be fine until I try to load the page, at which point my Express.js app throws the error

```
    [[sass] error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap. 
Parent style sheet: .../sass/app.scss at options.error (.../node-sass/lib/index.js:291:26)
```

I have tried npm install, restarting my server, looking on Google, StackOverflow (yes, I know there are quite a few similar questions, but none of them answer my question), the Bootstrap 4 GitHub issue pages and so far I haven't been able to come up with the answer.

Could it be that I installed the dependencies in the wrong place? (Dev instead of production or vis-à-vis)

Why am I getting this error??

My webpack.config.js file looks like this...

```
 module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'style-loader', // inject CSS to page
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader', // translate CSS into CommonJS modules
        }, {
          loader: 'postcss-loader', // run post CSS actions
          options: {
            plugins: function () { // post css plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
              return [
                require('precss'),
                require('autoprefixer')
              ];
            }
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader' // compile Sass to CSS
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My package.json file

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --ignore public/",
    "dev": "webpack -wd",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.11.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "precss": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.5",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.11",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.10",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
};
```

and inside app.scss I have

```
@import "custom";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: Try to import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" before everything else.

Comment: @DayOne I assume you’re referring to the `@import` inside app.scss. Is there any reason why that would make a difference? The two `@import` lines are the first two lines in the file, and they appear as indicated in the documentation found at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/

Comment: If I understand correctly, when Sass is precompiled by its own CLI, it processes `@imports` by itself, and thus doesn’t understand `~` notation. So you can import `@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` in first place or replaced the `~` notation with `node_modules/` instead it might work.

Comment: @DayOne okay, I’ll try that out. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @DayOne, sorry it took me so long to get back to you on this, but `"node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` did the trick; `"bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` did not. Please "Answer" so I can give you credit. I still don't understand why `node_modules/...` worked but `bootstrap/...` did not? In any case, +1. Thank you!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

When Sass is precompiled by its own CLI, it processes `@imports` by itself, and sometimes thus doesn’t understand `~` notation. So you can import `"node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` in first place and replaced the `~` 
 notation with `node_modules/` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work but I had to go back a few directories.: `@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

Comment: Are you saying that scss/functions directory does not need to exist?

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar error

> File to import not found or unreadable:
>   node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap

Just add     "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7", to devDependencies at yours package.json, ad  run npm update, npm install in your project directory.

Comment: this works for me adding "bootstrap-scss" and them @import "~bootstrap-scss/bootstrap";

Comment: Future readers: be careful to pick the correct package among `bootstrap`, `bootstrap-sass`, and `bootstrap-scss`. For the error described in the question, having **`bootstrap`**  as a dependency should have worked.

Answer (score 5):

For me, I had to change the way I was importing

```
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Then it works

Comment: This worked, thanks. The strange thing is, it was working when I initially set it all up, bet after I left it for the night and came back it just stopped.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 7.0.1, after installing using `rails new myapp --css=bootstrap`, the same error occured. The problem was solved by:

- Replacing the line with `stylesheet_link_tag` in `application.erb` by: `stylesheet_link_tag "application.bootstrap", "data-turbo-track": "reload"`
- renaming `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` by `app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss`
- Replacing the content by `@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

Answer (score 3):

I am not using webpack, but I got the same error when I try to import bootstrap in my scss file like this:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

It would work if I just import it like this in my case:

```
@import "../../../../../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But since That is not clean enough to my liking, I found out I could alter my gulp scss task from:

```
.pipe(plugins.sass())
```

to:

```
.pipe(plugins.sass({
    outputStyle: 'nested',
    precision: 3,
    errLogToConsole: true,
    includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss']
}))
```

(notice the includePaths section) and now I can just use

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

In my scss file

Comment: I expound on this 2020 approach a little bit here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65239936/2223106

Answer (score 1):

I am using Solidus and on the very first while getting bootstrap works with the solidus faced the same issue.
The below thing works for me as we have to show the full path where the bootsrap is.

```
@import "../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the fix for me was very basic in the end.

I just had to change `"../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` to `"node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you give import from node_modules in any scss file other than the base root `style.scss`. Try placing it in the root `style.scss`, it should do it.

Comment: I only have one scss file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having any issue and the answers fail to resolve try this:

1. Open up your scss file that tries to import.
2. Rectify the address of the import it might be trying from differnt space.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by:

- remove node_modules
- npm install
- ng serve

works ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just run `npm i bootstrap` and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This is similar to my problem, npx mix fail to import bootsrtap with error;

> SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.

Turns out my application root folder name using "#" that caused npx consider as unusual path and fail to import

[npx mix error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAjee.png)

Solution:

- Rename the folder (remove "#")
- Good to go

Hope this helps